# Characterization of a bounded operator with finite rank

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $H$ and $K$ two Hilbert spaces and let $T:H \rightarrow K$ be a bounded operator with finite rank, show that exists $\varphi_1,\ldots, \varphi_n \in H$ and $\phi_1,\ldots, \phi_n \in K$ such that
> $$T(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \langle f,\varphi_k \rangle \phi_k$$

I know that $H$ contains a ortonormal basis and any $x \in H$ can write like
$$x=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \langle x,e_i \rangle e_i$$
I think to the $\varphi'$s is a subset of these ortonormal basis, and how the rank is finite then the images of the $\varphi'$s generate the rank.
I not sure to these ideas are correct, any hint or help I will very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $(\phi_i)$ be an orthonormal basis of the range of $T$. Then we can write $Tx=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i(x) \phi_i$ for unique constants $a_i(x)$.  Now each $a_i$ is  map from $H$ into the scalar field. Apply Closed Graph Theroem to the function $x \to (a_1(x),a_2(x),...,a_n(x))$ to show that it is continuous. By Riesz Theorem we can write $a_i(x)= \langle x, \varphi_i \rangle$.

EDIT:  A simpler argument is in the comment below by Phoemuex.

Comment: Note: $a_i (x) = \langle T x, \phi_i\rangle = \langle x, T^\ast \phi_i\rangle$. No need for closed graph theorem.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thank you. I have taken the liberty of using your comment in my answer. I hope it is OK to do that.

Comment: Sure, that was the point.